# How to set focus/scrolltop to the first item in the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search form, when search button is clicked, it fetches data via ajax request and append into a div. Now, I need to automatically scrolltop to the first result of the search when items returned.How do I do that please?

script to set scrolltop:

```
$("#search").on("click",function(){
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#view2').offset().top//instead of #View2, how do I make the page scrolltop to the first item appended in the for loop below?
    }, 'slow');
});
```

When search button button clicked, results are fetched by ajax and appended into a div as below:

```
$("#searchform").on("submit", function () {
    //$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };        

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "search/ajax2.php",
        data: data,  
        success: function (data) {
            $(".the-inner-return").append("<a href='search2.php?TID="+ tid +"'>")//need to set the scrolltop here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way.

```
$("#search").on("click",function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementIdToWhichScroll").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Where **elementIdToWhichScroll** is your first element id.

EDIT CODE  -

```
success: function (data) {
         $(".the-inner-return").append("<a href='search2.php?TID="+ tid +"'>");

             $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#elementIdToWhichScroll").offset().top
        }, 'slow');

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery code

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#view2').offset().top//instead of #View2, how do I make the page scrolltop to the first item appended in the for loop below?
}, 'slow');

});
```

Comment: scrollTop: $('#view2').offset().top, how does this target the first item in the loop though?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Use this code for after getting result data with your div id or class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your animation into your ajax success callback. You can then use the `:last` pseudo to get the last anchor within that element (because you have appended it to the end, `prepend` would need `:first`).

http://jsfiddle.net/onj1yxdq/

```
success: function (data) {
    $('.the-inner-return').append("<a href='search2.php?TID="+ tid +"'>");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.the-inner-return a:last').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```